# How to connect to another Amazon Linux ec2 instance from an Amazon linux ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I have logged in to my amazon ec2 instance, using putty(as I am using windows). Now, I want to connect to another ec2 instance from here. 
What is the process ?

I am new to Cloud computing, so can you please tell me the steps clearly?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking to create an SSH tunnel, i.e. connect from your machine to a third machine, via an intermediate machine.

THis is often done for security purposes and the middle box is usually called a bastion host or jump box.

Here is some pretty detailed instructions:

https://linuxacademy.com/howtoguides/posts/show/topic/17385-use-putty-to-access-ec2-linux-instances-via-ssh-from-windows